# Embed Jupyterlab to website

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Can I embed JupyterLab into a website? Currently it throws frame-ancestors self error.  Is it possible to change some configuration to allow embedding this in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The default setup of both JupyterHub and single-user Jupyter Notebook/Lab server is configured to prohibit outside domains from embedding the page. As a workaround, you can include your domain in the frame-ancestors directive:

- [jupyterhub_config.py:](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/config-basics.html)

  ```
  c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
      'headers': {
          'Content-Security-Policy':
          "frame-ancestors 'self' http://yourdomain.com"
      }
  }
  ```
- [jupyter_notebook_config.py:](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)

  ```
  c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
      'headers': {
          'Content-Security-Policy':
          "frame-ancestors 'self' http://yourdomain.com"
      }
  }
  ```

If you are using a Kubernetes-based setup for the deployment, the configuration is slightly different and involves writing/building a Dockerfile of the single-user server with these configurations. You can check out [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/zcesur/embeddable-jhub-sample) that I created a while back that will walk you through these steps.